# Putting arrays into custom objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attempting to build my first custom object and it looks something like this:

```
function  URLObject()
{
   this.syllables = new Array();
   etc...

   this.AddtoSyllables = AddtoSyllables;
   function AddtoSyllables(AWord)
   {
       var SylCount = this.syllables.length;
       alert("This is SylCount: " + SylCount);
   }
}

var myobj = new URLObject();
myobj.AdtoSyllables("text");
```

The execution of the above code results in the JS engine printing out the following:

This is Sylcount:  NAN

-or-

This is SylCount:  undefined.

I have looked at information in Head First Javascript, in the Javascript bible, and on various JS websites.  All of them cover in exhaustive detail the use of arrays of objects, but none of them discuss arrays within objects.

And yet I am doing something wrong here and I do not know what.  Can anyone help?

Comment: myobj.AdtoSyllables("text"); should be myobj.AddtoSyllables("text"); ...

Comment: Which browser? The code works just fine for me (after fixing the typo).

Comment: Yeah, it might be useful to set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - it makes it very easy for people to see exactly what's going on and compare browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
function  URLObject()
{
   this.syllables = [];
   etc...
}

URLObject.prototype.addToSyllables = function(aWord) {
  var SylCount = this.syllables.length;
  alert("This is SylCount: " + SylCount);
}

var myobj = new URLObject();
myobj.adtoSyllables("text");
```

`.prototype` adds the function declared after it to every object constructed by the constructor function. (in your case every object that was instantiated by `new URLObject()`)

Comment: If you are going to change his solution to use prototypes, you should also take the time to explain them :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the code as posted actually works for me on Chrome and Firefox; so this must depend on the JavaScript engine, or else there's something funky going on.

**Update**: I suspect what may be confusing you is some separate call to `AddtoSyllables` (in code you haven't shown us) where suddenly `this.syllables` is no longer defined. This is where the behavior of `this` can get confusing. I've created a jsFiddle to hopefully explain how it works a bit better for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/J3tUb/

That said, it is often very possible to write code like this without having to use `this` (or the prototype) at all. For instance:

```
function createURLObject() {
   // Use closed-over locals instead of attaching properties.
   var syllables = new Array();

   function AddToSyllables(AWord) {
     // Since syllables is closed over, it is accessible here
     // (but WON'T be accessible outside this scope).
     syllables.push(AWord);
     return syllables.length;
   }

   // Expose whatever functionality you want to be "public"
   // in the returned object.
   return {
     AddToSyllables: AddToSyllables
   };
}

var myObj = createURLObject();
myObj.AddToSyllables("text");
```

It is, of course, valuable to understand JavaScript's quirky (and surprising, to most developers coming from other languages) behavior with respect to `this`. That said, once you do understand it, I suspect you will find that it can often be avoided altogether.

Comment: Ha. I like that you say that, but then use `this` in the example anyway... I do believe that the only way to completely avoid `this` for this example is to actually use the prototype (assuming you're not wanting to go `var x = new URLObject(); x.AddToSyllables = ...`)

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, yeah... nitpicker ;) I often go w/ closed-over locals instead of using `this` for object state, but still use `this` when declaring functions (as in the original example). However, it's certainly possible to avoid `this` *completely*, as I implied. I've updated the answer to show how.

Comment: The only trick with this is that if someone *does* use the prototype for something this will actually break it, unless I'm very much mistaken about how the `return` statement works - it won't receive any prototype members, right (other than Object ones)? Not that that's a problem, just something to be aware of. I do like the use of the completely private variables though, that's neat.

Comment: @Jeff: You're right—this "anti-`this`" approach works primarily if you decide to basically skip prototype-based inheritance completely. Mixing and matching code that uses `this` with code that doesn't can be a bit messy. For a great overview of this totally different way of writing JavaScript, see this blog post by an old colleague of mine: http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/02/06/class-less-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this :

```
function URLObject()
{
var that = this;
that.AddtoSyllables = AddtoSyllables;
function AddtoSyllables(AWord)
```

etc...
Like this you can add method and attributes to one object.

Comment: i recommend using the prototype solution as i posted.

Comment: @ndrizza Clearly. It's always good to have multiple answers though - it allows for users to more easily compare them and judge when each technique is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the function `AddtoSyllables` is not a *member function* or *method* of the `URLObject`. It is just a nested function with no object attachments, so all usages of `this` will result in returning the dom window object. The correct way of declaring the `AddtoSyllables` function is this:

```
function  URLObject()
{
    //...
}

URLObject.prototype.AddtoSyllables = function (AWord)
{
    var SylCount = this.syllables.length;
    alert("This is SylCount: " + SylCount);
}
```

---

To explain the reasons of the behavior in the question, I'd like to clarify that objects in javascript are treated like a map, dictionary or a key-value pair (use the term what suits you best). Using the syntax `x.y = value;` is equivalent putting the `value` value into the map `x` with key `y`. Having the code:

```
this.AddtoSyllables = AddtoSyllables;
function AddtoSyllables(AWord)
{
    var SylCount = this.syllables.length;
    alert("This is SylCount: " + SylCount);
}
```

adds the `AddtoSyllables` function as an entry to the object `this` points to. 
The code

```
myobj.AdtoSyllables(...)
```

is equivalent to

```
myobj["AdtoSyllables"](...) // now a retreiaval operation
```

or even

```
var fn = myobj["AdtoSyllables"];
fn (...);
```

Inside the `AdtoSyllables` function, `this` is used. Against common expectations, it is **not** a pointer to the `myobj`.

The cause of this is that `AddtoSyllables` is treated as a **static method** of the `URLObject` class (as OOP guys would understand it), or even a loose static function (like in C). To make JS treat it like a member of the `URLObject` object (an **instance method** to OOP guys), JS must be told to do so. This is achieved through  the `URLObject.prototype.AddtoSyllables = ....` which equivalents to declaration of an instance method.

---

From an alternative point of view:

```
function foo() { /* some code using `this` */ }
var bar = {};
var baz = {};

bar.foo = foo; // same as bar["foo"] = foo;
baz.foo = foo; // same az baz["foo"] = foo;
```

In the above code, `this` usages inside `foo` will neither point to `bar`, nor `baz`. At the same time `bar.foo` will point to the very same instance as `baz.foo`, for `foo` is also an object.

Comment: Actually... since it's called with `myobj.` it should be referring to the object, since that's now the scope of the function.

Comment: @Jeff, I have updated the answer to reflect your point, in an attempt to make it clear  using OOP analogies